# Using Repository pattern - selecting specific fields of the entity for EF performance reasons

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

So, I am having a hard time with this Repository pattern. In lots of articles, posts and etc. I read that the repository should return only database objects(no DTOs, no mappers inside the repository).So you return single database object or list of objects.

This is OK, but for EF(entity framework) performance reasons, it's OK to return only field's that you need, not the entire entity.

So, how are you supposed to do that with repository pattern? You cannot select the database object with specific fields because it is detached
(`ctx.Users.Select(new User(){ properties }).FirstOrDefault()`)
, you cannot return an anonymous object, and as I read it's not good practice to return `IQueryable<User>` and outside the repository to select desired fields.

Can you share some practice?

Comment: EF `DbSet<T>` itself is a repository implementation (`Find`, `Add`, `Remove` etc.), and as you can see, it allows you to use it as `IQueryable<T>`, so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We solved it with 2 types of generic functions. You can either use

- Automapper ProjectTo, which will define the mapping based on the generic type.
- Write a custom selector expression to return an anonymous object. (You can return anonymous objects if you pass it on and return the same generic, that's also what the `Select` method's signature looks like)

In both cases the repository doesn't return the entity anymore, but it's also not responsible for for the transformation of the object, instead the Automapper library, or the caller with the select expression are taking care of that.

Comment: Yes, I also like the idea with `Expression<Func<T,TResult>>`, but some developers think this is exposing the entity. Anyway maybe I will stick with your solution. I have one more layer( where I map entities to DTO and do some validations) before returning entities to the Controller, so I think this will help to encapsulate everything EF related.

Comment: well yeah, in your initial question you wrote *I read that the repository should return only database objects(no DTOs, no mappers inside the repository).* and that's also what we're doing and I suggested. Of course exposing entities is weird as well. But what we're doing, a service interface is never allowed to contain entities. So also other services using each other will always just communicate through DTOs and you have a nice fat layer of business logic using DTOs all over the place, with thin layers for Entities and Controller Models.